# Python - can't seem to find how to get a file through its path

Tags: python, file, sockets

pretty much what I intend on making is a program that, among other things, is able to get a file through its path and then send it to another socket (TCP protocol so no additional problems expected).

However, I'm trying to find a way to use the path of the file to send the file to the client and I just can't seem to find it... Any help would be appreciated =D ^^

Comment: You can open a file by its path with the `open()` built-in function.

Comment: okay, but I only saw with the open method a way to write to the files, not to read the file, copy it and send it in chunks. How can i use open() so i could read from the file?

Comment: have you try something already in code? share it in here, so we have a better understanding of your idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a socket and the `sendfile` method. There is some work to be done here for large files that go over the receive buffer size, but I'll leave that work to you.

`test.txt`

```
Hello World!
```

`server.py`

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 65432))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, client = s.accept()
        with conn:
            path = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            print(f'Client {client} requested file {path}')

            with open(path, "rb") as f:
                data = conn.sendfile(f)
```

`client.py`

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 65432))
    s.sendall(b'test.txt')
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()

print(f"Received data: {data}")
```

Outputs:

```
## server logs
Client ('127.0.0.1', 62999) requested file test.txt
## client logs
Received data: Hello World!
```

Comment: Hi man, thank you so much for sending the code snippet. If i had 15 rep I would've useful'd your answer ^^

Comment: Note that blindly `recv`ing 1024 bytes will probably not fly for very long - a real file transfer protocol would probably need a packet/command scheme.